# JS CryptoJS encrypted -> PHP OpenSSL decrypted: cipher changes length

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

I have a problem which I can't understand. I programmed some code to encrypt data in JS with CryptoJS and to decrypt this data in PHP with OpenSSL. Sometimes it work but most of the time it breaks

Code:

```
    PHP          JS
$passphrase == passkey
```

**JS:**

```
let data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, passkey).toString();
send(data);
```

**PHP:**

```
list($cipher, $salt) = decode($_POST["data"]);
list($passkey, $iv) = evpkdf($passphrase, $salt);

$data = openssl_decrypt($cipher, "AES-256-CBC", $passkey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
echo $data

function evpkdf($passphrase, $salt) {
    $salted = "";
    $dx = "";
    while(strlen($salted) < 48) {
        $dx = md5($dx . $passphrase . $salt, true);
        $salted .= $dx;
    }
    $passkey = substr($salted, 0, 32);
    $iv = substr($salted, 32, 16);

    return [$passkey, $iv];
}

function decode($data) {
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    if (substr($data, 0, 8) !== "Salted__") {
        // throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
        echo "no salt\n";
    }

    $salt = substr($data, 8, 8);
    $cipher = substr($data, 16);

    return [$cipher, $salt];
}
```

Results:

```
   PHP    JS
    iv == iv
  salt == salt
cipher ?? cipher
?? = sometimes
```

The only thing which I noticed was that the Cipher is not always the same length and only if the cipher has the right length it worked. What could be my error which I can't see. I already tried a lot and I really have no idea what to do. I tried to change the passkey in JS or to look if something else is different, but as above only the cipher doesn't make sense all the time.

Comment: I guess somewhere during transport you're missing out on bytes. Partial base 64 strings may still decode after all. The transport of base64 ciphertext and whatnot is however not in the code. Note that CBC encryption - by itself - is entirely insecure for transport mode security.

Comment: CryptoJS automatical makes the chipher obj to a base64 string with the toString() method. But it could be a solution. I try to send the data as hex string. And I know i should use RSA but I allready did. First the clients makes a pub- and privkey, sends me the pubkey and i encrypt the AES key with it. Now the client and me have the same key for encryption and decryption

Comment: Hey @MaartenBodewes Thank you. I have found the problem it was the base64 string as you said. Now everything works